# Why can Ryoma beat adults in the US tournaments but have trouble with high schoolers?

Tags: prince-of-tennis

If Ryoma's skills allowed him to go to the US, why did he lose against high schoolers who haven't even gone to the US in New Prince of Tennis?

Comment: This seems to be opinion-based.

Comment: Are we sure this can't be answered possibly from canon possibly?

Comment: Well the anime (don't know if canon) also implies many Japanese high schoolers are on par with US Open Juniors which is a world wide competition.

Comment: If I absolutely had to post an answer, it would be: "Because Tennis is not rocket science".